# Why do I keep facing a Mocha "timeout error"; Also node keeps telling me to resolve my promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I keep getting a timeout error, it keeps telling me to enusre I have called done(), even though I have.

```
  const mocha = require('mocha');

  const assert = require('assert');

  const Student = require('../models/student.js');

  describe('CRUD Tests',function(){
     it('Create Record',function(done){
         var s = new Student({
            name: "Yash"
         });

         s.save().then(function(){
            assert(s.isNew === false);

            done();
         });
     });
 });
```

Result is -

> CRUD Tests
>       1) Create Record
>
> 0 passing (2s)   1 failing
>
> 1) CRUD Tests
>          Create Record:
>        Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure  it
>   resolves.
>   (/home/yash/Documents/Development/Node/MongoCRUD/test/CRUD_test.js)

Answer (score 1):

I guess that your mocha runs without being connected to your database. So `.save()` is waiting for a connection which it never get and your mocha timeout.

---

You can initialize your software system before to run any Mocha test.

For example, connect a database.

```
// ROOT HOOK Executed before the test run
before(async () => {
    // connect to the database here
});

// ROOT HOOK Excuted after every tests finished
after(async () => {
    // Disconnect from the database here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that as written, your unit test ignores the fact that `save()` might *reject* instead of resolving. Whenever you use this `done` construct, make sure your unit test handles an error scenario, like this:

```
     s.save().then(function() {
        assert(s.isNew === false);

        done();
     }).catch(error => {
        done(error);
     });
```

Alternatively, since Mocha has built-in support for promises, you can *remove* the `done` parameter and return the promise directly, like this:

```
it('Create Record', function() {
    // ...

    return s.save().then(function() {
        assert(s.isNew === false);
     });
});
```

The advantage with this approach is a reject promise will automatically fail the test, and you don't need any `done()` calls.